# PHP_VALUE in nginx.conf doesn't override parameters in php.ini

Tags: php, nginx, config, fastcgi, php-ini

I have this location section in nginx.conf:

```
location ~ \.php {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   PHP_VALUE   "memory_limit = 500M; post_max_size = 400M; upload_max_filesize = 300M";
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

I need to increase these parameters for file downloading, but there're still previous values of php.ini in `phpinfo()`-list, despite updated  $_SERVER['PHP_VALUE'] (contains values written by me in the config). I'd tried to change values in different ways: without semicolon, with `\n`, mixed both the previous variations, replaced `PHP_VALUE` with `PHP_ADMIN_VALUE`, copied the param from others' config; but it still was unsuccessful. Where's the problem? What obstruct to apply my params?

Comment: I didn't also forget to reload/restart nginx

Comment: which OS and what version of PHP and FPM? Did you try restarting FPM also?

Comment: Oh, I do it on Windows via php-cgi just like [there](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfastcgionwindows/)

Comment: What you are doing is for PHP-FPM, not sure of PHP-CGI also supports that

Answer (score 6):

For me, it worked in this format -

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "variable1=value1;\n variable2=value2; \n variable3=value3;";
```

Comment: Or you can include actual newlines.

Answer (score 4):

```
fastcgi_param   PHP_VALUE   "memory_limit = 500M; post_max_size =
400M; upload_max_filesize = 300M";
```

last parameter without semicolon

```
fastcgi_param   PHP_VALUE   "memory_limit = 500M; post_max_size = 400M; upload_max_filesize = 300M;";
```